# スポーツと礼の関係について translation

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

Today I came across the sentence,
「日本のスポーツと礼の関係について話しています。」
I scratched my head looking at this initially thinking the meaning of 関係 is relation/relationship, connection.
Then I found out 関係 also has the meaning on (involvement). 
Does that mean this sentence translated to (Talking about Japanese sports and proper etiquette’s involvement/role)?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering if "sportsmanship" is a good translation for スポーツと礼の関係 .

Comment: @charlemagne it is a valid translation, but don't you think it's too "interpreted"

Comment: @rebuuilt Yeah I see your point, but doesn't it depend on context?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to overthink. AとBの関係 is just "relationship between A and B".

> (<日本のスポーツ>と<礼>の関係)について話しています。
>
> [Someone] is talking about (the relationship between <Japanese sports> and <*rei*>).

礼 basically means bowing, but as you know, it implies much more, and that's the theme of the speech. Still, the grammar of this sentence itself is simple.

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to try not to over think these things I guess!